# Duplicate AngularJS-related tags: [angularjs-ng-*] and [ng-*]

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

We have:

- [angularjs-ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-repeat) (1,643 questions, wiki) and [ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-repeat) (339 questions, no wiki)
- [angularjs-ng-options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-options) (13 questions, no wiki) and [ng-options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-options) (131 questions, wiki)
- [angularjs-ng-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-model) (6 questions, wiki) and [angular-ngmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ngmodel) (120 questions, wiki)

Also, there's just a [general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-*) [inconsistency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-*) in names of such tags.

While I don't think there's much point in trying to get all those tags consistently named, I suggest making the ones I listed synonyms - I personally prefer to keep more explicit ones (prefixed with angularjs-ng-)

Comment: I’d rather make all of them synonyms of [tag:angular], since tags for specific tags ([tag:div], anyone?) are pointless! Some people disagree recently, though.