# Burninate 73 AngularJS directive tags

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

There have been questions about the merits of specialized tags ([Burninate specific event tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268953/burninate-specific-event-tags)) and the redundancy of some tags related to AngularJS (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250923/duplicate-tags-ui-select2-and-angularjs-select2 and [Duplicate AngularJS-related tags: [angularjs-ng-*] and [ng-*]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266598/duplicate-angularjs-related-tags-angularjs-ng-and-ng)) as well as whether there should be version-specific tags ([Should there be a separate 'angularjs-2.0' tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291347/should-there-be-a-separate-angularjs-2-0-tag)). And the plethora of tags was also discussed in [Asking an [angular-ng-*] question is as easy as picking from four different tag formats](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283216/asking-an-angular-ng-question-is-as-easy-as-picking-from-four-different-tag).

[edit] Previous discussions have proposed tidying up by duping or merging tags - I think we need to go further.

I propose collapsing the 73+ sub-tags of AngularJS into [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs). The observations that drive this are:

- 100,428 questions are tagged [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs), which has about 15,500 followers. That's a healthy community, able to provide excellent monitoring and hygiene of incoming questions.
- In addition to the main [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) tag, there are more than 70 "sub-tags":
  [angular-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-bootstrap)
  [angular-dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-dart)
  [angular-directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-directive)
  [angular-filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-filters)
  [angular-google-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-google-maps)
  [angular-http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-http)
  [angular-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material)
  [angular-ng-if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ng-if)
  [angular-ngmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ngmodel)
  [angular-promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-promise)
  [angular-resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-resource)
  [angular-routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-routing)
  [angular-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-services)
  [angular-strap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-strap)
  [angular-translate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-translate)
  [angular-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ui)
  [angular-ui-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ui-bootstrap)
  [angular-ui-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ui-grid)
  [angular-ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ui-router)
  [angular-ui-typeahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ui-typeahead)
  [angularjs-animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-animation)
  [angularjs-controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-controller)
  [angularjs-directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-directive)
  [angularjs-e2e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-e2e)
  [angularjs-factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-factory)
  [angularjs-filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-filter)
  [angularjs-http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-http)
  [angularjs-module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-module)
  [angularjs-ng-change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-change)
  [angularjs-ng-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-class)
  [angularjs-ng-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-click)
  [angularjs-ng-focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-focus)
  [angularjs-ng-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-form)
  [angularjs-ng-hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-hint)
  [angularjs-ng-href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-href)
  [angularjs-ng-if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-if)
  [angularjs-ng-include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-include)
  [angularjs-ng-init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-init)
  [angularjs-ng-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-model)
  [angularjs-ng-options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-options)
  [angularjs-ng-pluralize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-pluralize)
  [angularjs-ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-repeat)
  [angularjs-ng-route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-route)
  [angularjs-ng-show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-show)
  [angularjs-ng-submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-submit)
  [angularjs-ng-template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-template)
  [angularjs-ng-touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-touch)
  [angularjs-ng-transclude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-transclude)
  [angularjs-orderby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-orderby)
  [angularjs-resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-resource)
  [angularjs-routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-routing)
  [angularjs-scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-scope)
  [angularjs-select2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-select2)
  [angularjs-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-service)
  [ng-animate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-animate)
  [ng-bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-bind)
  [ng-bind-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-bind-html)
  [ng-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-class)
  [ng-dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-dialog)
  [ng-flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-flow)
  [ng-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-grid)
  [ng-hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-hide)
  [ng-html2js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-html2js)
  [ng-init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-init)
  [ng-map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-map)
  [ng-options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-options)
  [ng-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-pattern)
  [ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-repeat)
  [ng-show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-show)
  [ng-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-style)
  [ng-submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-submit)
  [ng-switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-switch)
  [ng-tags-input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-tags-input)
  [ng-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-view)
- The vast majority of questions with those sub-tags are also tagged [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs), but another 18,883 (or so) are not. **This is the worst outcome of tag-arama, questions aren't getting in front of the large, ready audience monitoring** [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs)**.**
- Many of the sub-tags are lightly followed, or not followed at all. (See spreadsheet link at bottom of this question.)
- New sub-tags keep getting added, possibly because there's already a pattern of tag-every-directive.

  *What language deserves a specialized tag for* `if`, *for example?* Well, [angularjs-ng-if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-if) was added this week, by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30787147/angularjs-ng-if-and-scopes), so AngularJS had **two**! (I retagged it [angular-ng-if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ng-if), one tag down...)

  There were 19 new sub-tags added in the past month, 7 of those this week. (Spot the synonyms!) [textangular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/textangular)
  [angular-seo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-seo)
  [angularjs-rootscope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-rootscope) ([rootscope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rootscope))
  [angularjs-lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-lifecycle)
  [angularjs-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-forms)
  [angular-chosen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-chosen)
  [angularjs-promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-promise)
  [angularjs-ng-if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-if)
  [angular-meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-meteor)
  [angular-new-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-new-router)
  [angular-timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-timer)
  [angularjs-new-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-new-router)
  [angularjs-ng-pluralize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-pluralize)
  [angularjs-ng-submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-submit)
  [angularjs-ng-class-odd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-class-odd)
  [angularjs-ng-class-even](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-class-even)
  [angular-formly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-formly)
  [angular-ui-datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ui-datepicker)

Cleaning this up is too big a job for little ol' me. Can we get some programmatic help to end the insanity?

I've collected some stats on these tags in [a spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jz9EkW2nUpUV61UKUc_5I3e8ppcxaAf0hB6cJvPxfAE/pubhtml).

Comment: After a quick look at your spreadcheat I am inclined to say that I was right in wanting to keep [tag:angular-directive].

Comment: [I think you may have missed some](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283216/359284), there are (at least) three different prefixes used for AngularJS tags.

Comment: @KevinBrown - Ouch! I wish I'd found your question before I started this journey! I figured there were more; there are so many that wildcard searches result in strings that are too long for the input box. Because of that, I couldn't easily obtain an accurate count of the number of questions that were tagged with "sub-tags" but not [tag:angularjs].

Comment: @KevinBrown - foiled by [a bug](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296894/paging-not-provided-on-search-results) in tag searching, if results are larger than a page! How else can we find all the tags?

Comment: I would argue for keeping tags that relate to specific repos.

Comment: Why hasn't someone come along and made a corny pun with this burninate request?

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen: The right angle just hasn't occurred to anyone yet.

Comment: You could say the angularjs tag family has taken a *turn* for the worse.

Comment: *"Is the angularjs directive tags too obtuse?"*...ok, maybe not

Comment: This comment wall has _diverged_ from the topic.

Comment: That's quite an *acute* observation you made there.

Comment: Is having these sub tags really a bad thing? If they all added the AngularJS tag then there won't be any problem at all. In fact, users can also look for questions more specifically to answer.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I can see arguments for some of the sub tags, but the vast majority of them seem way too specific.  I can't think of a good reason to have a tag for `ng-if`, for example.

Comment: @Beofett In that case, maybe we should get rid off those that seem too specific, and leave the ones that are less specific alone, such as angular-promise.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 After reading [Shog9's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297000/664342), I think it probably makes sense to leave even the ones that seem too specific for now, and instead focus on cleaning up the ones prefixed with `angularjs-`.  While I'm not convinced `ng-if` or `ng-show` really **need** their own tags, they don't actively hurt, and I can understand the argument for directive-specific tags in general.

Comment: @Beofett I agree that fixing the prefixes should be focused on right now.

Comment: I saw someone edit a question with the sole purpose of adding a [tag:angularjs-service] tag earlier. I'm confused as to why this level of granularity is really necessary. No other framework appears to have this. I can understand having [tag:angular-ui] and [tag:angular-ng-route], but it seems silly to have sub-tags for the *core* parts of a framework.

Comment: `angular-translate` is a separate entity. It's not part of AngularJS, it's a library.

Answer (score 41):

Out of the "sub-tags" you have listed I count at least two that need to be kept:

- [angular-dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-dart)
- [angular-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ui)

In that case, [angular-ui-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ui-bootstrap), [angular-ui-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ui-grid), [angular-ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ui-router) and [angular-ui-typeahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ui-typeahead) could collapse into [angular-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ui).

---

Disclaimer: subjective opinion oncoming

1.X directives were complex enough to warrant a separate [angular-directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-directive) tag.
Since [angularjs-ng-route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-route) is not part of the core anymore it shouldn't be "collapsed" into the generic [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs). Even if we had/add a [angularjs-1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-1.0) tag it couldn't hold it because it still exists with the same name.

Comment: There are possibly more groupings, and there a few that should survive - [tag:angular-e2e] was another I'd wondered about. In the spreadsheet I pulled together, each tag that has 20% or more questions without overlap with [tag:angularjs] need special attention. Still, it might suppress recurrence of tag-arama if these separate topics get renamed in some way to not _appear_ to be "sub-tags".

Comment: @Mogsdad anything not considered part of the core should, if it has enough traction, be warranted a tag. [tag:angularjs-ng-route] is a special case that comes to mind since it's not builtin *anymore*.

Comment: Define "traction", given that when created, a tag will have one question, and no subscribers. Lots of these are in one or both of those situations. If traction is defined by use, then who monitors for non-use, and at what point do unused tags get cleaned up?

Comment: I disagree with rolling all the angular-ui tags up. Each one of those tags listed are maintained in separate repos and by different people. I filter on angular-ui- bootstrap and would find it cumbersome to have them all lumped together.

Comment: @RobJ join the discussion, then - We could use some additional concrete suggestions from someone really involved answering these. You must admit, the tags are a mess. What would you suggest, if "doing nothing" wasn't an option?

Comment: I can assure that the [tag:angular-promise] and [tag:angular-scope] tags are warranted to stand on their own. I guess -directive, -routing, -service, -controller, -factory, -http are also valid.

Comment: @Bergi +1 on keeping scope and promise. But your statement lacks a rationale. For example that there are [differences](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#differences-between-kris-kowal-s-q-and-q) between [tag:q] and [tag:angular-promise].

Comment: @Knu: That has been [too obvious](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14824733/4) to me…

Comment: `angular-translate` is a separate entity as well. It's not part of AngularJS, it's a library.

Comment: same goes for [angular-ui-router], which is not absolutely not related to [angular-ui-bootstrap]. angular-ui  stand for multiple libraries very used along with angular,  however each of them are independant, they musn't be mixed together

Answer (score 18):

**I think you should be a bit cautious here**; some of these tags are both unambiguous and fairly heavily used. If a tag isn't causing *harm* and is potentially *useful*, there's no reason to invest time and effort in getting rid of it.

For instance, [ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-repeat). I see no evidence that this is in any way ambiguous; it means one thing and one thing only; if you have a question about this particular directive, then using the tag makes good sense.

In contrast, [angularjs-ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-repeat) appears to be used on some questions that have no connection to the ng-repeat directive *at all!* I strongly suspect that the *angularjs* prefix led some number of authors to choose it accidentally. A useful activity then would be to [retag these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-repeat+-angularjs) into those tagged [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) and those with both [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) *and* [ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-repeat). Once done, the tag could be merged into and synonymized with [ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-repeat).

The same should be done for many if not most of these tags. Strive to convert prefixed tags to unprefixed tags whenever possible, remove ambiguous and misused tags ruthlessly, and **don't worry about the rest.**

Comment: Great point wrt accidental choice of a tag starting with `angular`. We see that with a variety of `google` tags as well - I think it's a fairly common behaviour. When selecting which synonymous tags to keep then, the choice should be to start with `ng-`.

Comment: ng-repeat is just too specific to warrant a tag IMO, not like I don't agree with you but I don't afree with your example.

Comment: What about the case where unprefixing a tag makes it ambiguous? It seems that people is cherry picking that without the "remove ambiguous and misused tags ruthlessly" qualifier. BTW, I prefer unambigousness over everything. If that makes a tag with two prefixes, maybe we don't need the root tag and just use the prefix.

Answer (score 8):

### Notes

- **Please do not bother unless you have [full editing rights](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)**, you'll be wasting the time of people in the edit review queue.
- Start on the tags with the fewest number of questions, once we clean up the larger tags the mods can take over.
- If a question is not on topic, *keep the original tag on the question* and flag it to be closed.
- When you retag a question, **also take the time to correct spelling and formatting**, fix other tags, improve the title, and improve the post.

### Progress report

The following tags will need to be handled under this request.

- [ngcloak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ngcloak) (11)
- [ng-init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-init) (14)
- [angularjs-ng-href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-href) (17)
- [ng-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-style) (33)
- [ng-submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-submit) (30)
- [ng-bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-bind) (55)
- [angularjs-ng-transclude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-transclude) (55)
- [angularjs-ng-show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-show) (56)
- [angularjs-ng-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-form) (57)
- [angularjs-ng-init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-init) (64)
- [ng-hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-hide) (72)
- [ng-switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-switch) (86)
- [ng-bind-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-bind-html) (88)
- [angularjs-ng-change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-change) (91)
- [angularjs-ng-options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-options) (94)
- [angular-ng-if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ng-if) (113)
- [angularjs-ng-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-model) (135)
- [ng-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-view) (139)
- [angularjs-ng-include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-include) (247)
- [ng-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-class) (249)
- [ng-show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-show) (209)
- [angular-ngmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ngmodel) (416)
- [angularjs-ng-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-click) (460)
- [ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-repeat) (851)
- [angularjs-ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-repeat) (3573)

Comment: I like your choice of grammar in the area where you bolded **also take the time to correcting spelling and formatting**.  Bypassing edit per suggestion. =)

Comment: @cchamberlain That actually wasn't intentional (but now I wish it was), I copied it from another post and missed that when rewording it.

Comment: Hmm... Of those that need to be removed, most if not all could be **merged** with [tag:angularjs]. Get a moderator to assist. Try to focus editing on areas where a simple merge will not suffice: disambiguation, splitting (for instance, [tag:angularjs-ng-repeat] -> [tag:angularjs], [tag:ng-repeat]).

Comment: This answer doesn't provide any guidance about merging tags or de-prefixing them.

Comment: FYI: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321050/maybe-synonims-ng-grid-and-angular-ui-grid

Comment: I just came upon this, it seems like 1 year later it still not done, should we still follow what is said here if we see a angular-xxx (among those which are not 3rd party components) tag ?

Answer (score 6):

Not all tags that start with "angular" or "ng" are for AngularJS directives, and not all directives following that naming convention were created by Angular. Quite a few of them are actually third party Angular components, which I think deserve their own tag.

- [angular-chosen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-chosen) - [Angular plugin](https://github.com/localytics/angular-chosen)
- [angular-google-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-google-maps) - [Angular UI component](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps) ([maybe?](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps))
- [angularjs-select2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-select2) - Actually should be [ui-select2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ui-select2)
- [angular-strap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-strap) - [AngularStrap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/)
- [angular-translate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-translate) - [Angular plugin](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate)
- [angular-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ui) - [Angular UI](https://angular-ui.github.io/) is not Angular, but these could use a clean up as well

And some of the tags aren't directives, and arguably are complex or different enough to deserve their own tag

- [angular-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-bootstrap) (when referring to the [Angular submodule](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap))
- [angularjs-controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-controller)
- [angular-dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-dart) - [A port of Angular to Dart](https://angulardart.org/)
- [angular-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material) - [Material design for Angular](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/)
- [angular-promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-promise)
- [angularjs-resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-resource)
- [angularjs-scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-scope)

But I agree that the tags involving core Angular directives should be merged into (or made a synonym of) [angular-directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-directive).