# Paging not provided on search results

Tags: bug, tag-search

When you first navigate to the [tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) you're greeted by a page of tags with page navigation at the bottom.

[image: lotsnlotso'tags]

Once you place a search string into the inputbox, page navigation disappears. Here's a screenshot of the [names tab](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=name) (sorted alphabetically) with a two letter search for `ng`, which we can expect to have many matches. It appears to, since the result only covers [.net-remoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-remoting) to [alternate-access-mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alternate-access-mappings). Yet, there's no page navigation offered.

[image: OMG! Looks like a bug to me.]

PS: Chrome Version 43.0.2357.81 m

Comment: Yeah, I just confirmed it. As soon as you type any character into the search box the page navigation disappears.

Comment: There is no such information as the number of results from the xhr response, only the content of `<table id='tags-browser'>`.  Also there is no parameter to tell how much responses we want from the request. So in my mind this is not really a bug but a muchover a lack of feature.

Comment: @Kaiido - nope, not a lack of feature. There _is_ a feature - "search". Users have a reasonable expectation that the feature will find matches to a search term. However, the results do not meet that expectation. That's a bug. (Now, if it was "search for first 36", you'd have a point.)

Comment: @Mogsdad my point was that it's not something literally broken, that we can try to fix or workaround, (like a bug we get off the machine), but rather something that isn't implemented yet. But my english is not fluent enough to allow me to play with words with you. Anyway, I did upvote your question ( I hope my first comment didn't sound like I disagreed with it )  and I hope the issue, whatever we call it, will be fixed.

Comment: @Kaiido - Thanks for the clarification, I understand now. You're right- it looks like an unfinished implementation.