# May be synonyms: [ng-grid] and [angular-ui-grid]

Tags: support, synonym-request

I'm not a professional at AngularJS UI Grid, but these tags seem to be synonyms, from my point of view:

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angular-ui-grid/info

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ng-grid/info

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296857/burninate-73-angularjs-directive-tags

Comment: This is not *quite* the same. The [ng-grid component changed its name to ui-grid a while back](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-grid/), to fit in with the other angular-ui components, and to not hijack the ng- prefix, which should only be used by AngularJS components. So, questions regarding the old version, should perhaps be tagged with [tag:ng-grid]?