# You're out of [order]! You're out of [order]! The whole site is out of [order]!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

[order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order) (not [orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orders))

It's got 7.3k questions and 64 followers, but is horribly ambiguous. The excerpt isn't helpful either (there's no wiki)

> Use this tag for specific questions about the order of results

From the *first page alone* I see questions related to

- Amazon orders
- E-commerce orders
- Ordering SQL results
- Order of execution of Python events
- Order of operations in C

There's little commonality here and new users are [clearly being confused by it](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37562787/1). In every case I've looked at the question would be fine without the tag (or a more specific tag that defines the question). The SQL questions should be retagged as [sql-order-by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-order-by), order of operations should have [order-of-operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order-of-operations), etc. The specific tags tie those questions together in a way this tag can't.

Comment: Thanks for posting this request and allowing the community to weigh in! Please note that burninating a tag is the process of carefully moderating a specific piece of Stack Overflow (please think twice before doing tag-only mass edits, as they can be counter-productive); once the community reaches a consensus, burnination can proceed. For more info, see [What is the process for burninating tags?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070).

Comment: There are some questions that mention SQL and might be asking about the SQL "order by" clause but are not tagged with any SQL tags. [Search Query](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5border%5d%20sql%20-%5bsql%5d%20-%5bmysql%5d%20-%5bsql-server%5d%20-%5boracle%5d%20-%5btsql%5d%20is%3aq). These could probably use some cleanup.

Comment: But for [tag:orders] tag when used in an [tag:e-commerce] context, it has some sense, **but only in this specific case**. So you can't remove like this all [tag:orders] tags because you have post this question here. The ambiguity is when it's out of this particular context. see my answer below. Thanks

Comment: [order] is perfectly well-defined in R language (where its meaning is similar to SQL): the order of a dataframe/table/matrix/plot/CSV file/etc.. So do not punish R users for other languages' misuse. Yes, in those contexts it is often important enough to have as tag, so having it in title is not enough.

Comment: @smci You're missing that **it's rarely used like that**. Of 7599 questions, only 683 are tagged [r]. If there's a usage here that's legitimate, we clearly need a new tag for it that removes the ambiguity.

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring: Q: +87/-4. A1 (Saying yes): +52/-1. A2 (Saying yes): +4/-1

Comment: **Moderator Note**: Please do not start removing the tag from questions until the community has decided whether to move forward with the burnination or not.

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring: Q: +118/-5. A1 (Saying Yes)  +71/-2. A2 (Saying Yes) +9/-2 A3 (Saying Yes) + 7/0. The community has voted in favor of the burnination.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

6.5k questions is a lot. This tag is awful though, and it should be ditched in favor of better tags. We might as well consider ditching the plurality too: [orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orders).

In any case, I think it's good to retag any questions that would be better off with other tags:

- [These questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Border%5D+%22order+by%22+is%3Aquestion) should be tagged with [sql-order-by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-order-by)
- *(Editor's Note: Now that burnination has started, see the [community burnination answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379337/712765) for more guidance.)* <strike>Questions about [order-of-operations] [order-of-evaluation] [order-of-execution] should be tagged with the corresponding tag. I'm not actually sure what the difference between these three tags is, or if we need all of them.</strike>
- [Questions about the AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Border%5D++angularjs+%22orderby%22) construct should use [angularjs-orderby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-orderby)
- For binary tree traversal, use [preorder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/preorder), [inorder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inorder), or [postorder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postorder)
- [z-order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/z-order)

I have only drawn up a really quick list of things, so I might have missed some things. Let me know if I should add anything.

Comment: Yeah, `orders` needs to go too, but the guidelines say one tag per question. With only 140 questions it's an easier burninate than this one

Comment: @Machavity [This question disagrees.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296857) :)

Comment: `order-of-operations` is akin to `*` before `-`. `order-of-evaluation` and `order-of-execution` are probably the same though since the former refers to what order things are evaluated in, such as what `int i = 1; i++, i *= 2;` sets `i` to. I can't think of an instance where someone would say `order-of-execution` and not mean `order-of-evaluation` outside of really specific questions with regards to re-ordering of statements (and it feels like anything like that should have a different tag).

Comment: I agree. This tag is vague and extremely broad and so is the [tag:orders] tag. I declare burniation of both tags!

Comment: What about [tag:sorting]? Not sure whether it should go or we should retag things to it.

Comment: @jpmc26 That has 37 THOUSAND questions tagged with it. I'm not ready for that yet...

Comment: Fair enough, but do we want to retag things to it? "Sorting" is a bit more explicit than "order" and is unlikely to attract things like shopping orders.

Comment: @jpmc26 I think that having the word "order" or "sort" (etc.) is enough. Especially if it's in the title.

Comment: Mostly good, except [order] is perfectly well-defined in R language (where its meaning is similar to SQL): the order of a dataframe/table/matrix/plot/CSV file/etc.. So do not punish R users for other languages' misuse. Yes, in those contexts it is often important enough to have as tag, so having it in title is not enough.

Comment: @smci [r-order] would probably work and be clear, although someone familiar with r might be able to name it better

Comment: @Laurel: I am familiar with R, and it should be named [order]. As I mention this is similar to usage in SQL, Python pandas, numpy etc. hence we totally can't rename it. Machavity: [tag:order] would presumably be used more in R, if the tag utility was not reduced by the big mess, so one more reason to cleanup/ add different tags for the other cases identified here. Let us get on with creating tags for the other cases, esp. e-commerce/shopping...?

Comment: @smci Tags for R things are disambiguated by prefixing with "r-", such as the [[r-factor\]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r-factor/info) tag. The fact that the [order] tag is misused as is means that it needs disambiguation, so it should be called [r-order].

Comment: @Laurel. No. Please listen to what I'm saying for the third time now: I explained that this concept [**order**] as in row/column-order of a dataframe/table/matrix/series/plot/CSV file/etc. is important **in R, SQL, Python pandas, numpy etc. It's the same concept across those languages**. Therefore use the same tag. It's not uniquely an R concept, so no r-tag. The actionable thing is to create and retag [ecommerce-orders] or [shopping-orders]. As for [order-of-execution]/evaluation are yet other meanings, they seem to deserve their own tag(s), but I can't comment on whether those can be merged.

Comment: @smci oh sorry. I’m still not convinced we need the order tag though since if it’s a question about ordering something the title is the best bet for that info.

Comment: @Laurel: Well is there at least consensus that there's a need for [ecommerce-orders]/[shopping-orders] (which?), even if partially as a defense to [order] being overrun with those. So back to when doing heavy 2D data processing (R, SQL, Python pandas, numpy etc.), people do some really complicated things with order (nesting, group-bys, multi-indexes/compound keys, reordering categorical levels) etc., all of which falls under [order] although plaintext-search would need ~20 different keywords. I will gather my thoughts into an answer with citations. Meanwhile can we create [ecommerce-orders]?

Comment: @smci if there’s not already a tag like it it sounds like a good idea to create ecommerce -orders

Comment: We're going to need a great big granddaddy dragon.

Comment: @smci do we need an "order" tag? Why exactly? What changes so much between orders, invoices or requests for services?

Comment: @smci I think that because "order" is so overloaded with meanings, we cannot keep it. (To mean everything is to mean nothing.) We have a "sql-order-by" tag for people working with SQL, and other people doing 2D data processing can be directed to use the "sorting" tag.

Comment: @OldPro: yeah I've reluctantly come around to that viewpoint that any general [tag:order' tag will be abused. But still, the handful of more specific topics, [tag:sql-order-by], [tag:order-of-evaluation]/[tag:order-of-execution], [tag:z-order], deserve individual topics.

Comment: Guys follow up question, is there a tag for NoSQL order related scenarios? I can only see `sql-order-by` tag

Comment: @MenukaIshan NoSQL is not a standard, so there is no standard way to sort, unlike with SQL and `ORDER BY`, so it doesn't really make sense to have a specific NoSQL ordering tag. For NoSQL ordering, I suggest tagging with the name of the database, e.g. [tag:mongodb], or [tag:nosql] if it is a more generic question, plus [tag:sorting].

Comment: Which tag should be used for [the mathematical concept of order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_theory)? It's a pretty essential concept in programming as well, with just about every language having built-in operators to determine order (`<` and `>` etc.) and Haskell having the type class `Ord` to provide said functionality. `ordering` would be my preferred tag, but this is currently a synonym of `order`

Comment: @glennsl I have never heard the expression "order theory" so that would not even be a connection I would make. We do have the obscure tag [tag:relational-operators], which might work for questions like that.

Comment: There are two major traditions in the history of programming language. One tries to build robust languages based on fundamental building blocks often derived from mathematics because it is a tradition that has thought about these things for centuries. The other tradition flails around until they accidentally stumble across something that happens to work. "ordering" is a term that comes from the former tradition, and "relational operators" comes from the latter.

Comment: More specifically, "relational operators" confuses the concepts of ordering and equality and assumes every language includes "operators" as a syntactic construct. It is therefore inaccurate and not applicable across all programming languages. "Ordering" is.

Comment: The wikipedia article on relational operators even includes [a section on "ordering"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_operator#Ordering)

Answer (score 24):

[order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

Unlike some other tags that have been burninated, [order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order) is not generally suggestive of a question that should be closed or deleted. We are getting rid of it because it is ambiguous, not bad per se. So most questions tagged [order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order) can and should simply be retagged. Delete the [order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order) tag and replace it with one of the following tags, if appropriate:

- [Questions related to the SQL `ORDER BY` clause](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Border%5D+%22order+by%22+is%3Aquestion) should be tagged with [sql-order-by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-order-by)
- Questions about ordering (putting in order) a collection of elements (other than via SQL) should be tagged [sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sorting)
- Questions about the order in which operators are evaluated as part of an expression or statement in a programming language should be tagged with [operator-precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/operator-precedence) (which tag is also [under consideration to merge with](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/379343) [order-of-operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order-of-operations) and [order-of-evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order-of-evaluation))
- Questions about the order in which things happen in a system (e.g. the order in which event handlers are called in JavaScript) and which are therefore at a higher level than a single expression or statement should be tagged [order-of-execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order-of-execution)
- [Questions about the AngularJS `orderBy`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Border%5D++angularjs+%22orderby%22) construct should use [angularjs-orderby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-orderby)
- For binary tree traversal, use [preorder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/preorder), [inorder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inorder), or [postorder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postorder)
- [z-order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/z-order) should be used for questions related to the overlapping order of 2D elements.
- [orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orders) should be used for for e-commerce related questions

## Progress:

The [order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=order),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Border%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Border%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Border%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Border%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## [Track the progress of the burnination!](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187135/)

[image]

#### Large Tag Guidance

Remember that [order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order) has more than 7000 questions! Therefore do not go through all of them! Retag the ones which are worth saving (usually the top voted posts) and Vote to Close (VtC) the unsalvageable questions (usually the very low scored).

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance".

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order) tag— just flag/vote to close the question.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/) for real-time advice and discussion.

Comment: I think that the graph would make humans feel less helpless if log is used for the vertical axis.

Comment: Oh, don't worry about that. It'll be like that just for a few days, after which we can see a slope. (check the design one, for eg https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcseA.png)

Answer (score 11):

The new tag Wiki is even worse than the one listed in the question:

> THIS TAG IS CONFUSING, DO NOT USE IT. Use [sorting] instead or [sql-order-by] to refer to ordering within a SQL statement. For other ordering, consider [order-of-operations] or [order-of-evaluation]. This tag is slated for removal.

The tag Wiki actually lists 3 reasons to burninate this:

- It's confusing and should not be used
- It lists several possible replacement usages. This implies that [order] can mean different things in different contexts, which is absolutely a reason to remove the tag.
- It describes the tag as being "slated for removal." I actually haven't been able to find where the usage guidance got this, but it's interesting that it suggests that it *ought* to be removed.

I say we burninate it.

Answer (score 7):

> Yes [order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order) tag is very ambiguous, I agree completely.

---

Now **for the tag [orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orders)**, there is only one case where it has really some sense: 
It's when is used in an **[e-commerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/e-commerce)** context, like with [magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magento), [shopify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shopify), [prestashop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prestashop), [woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/woocommerce) or other similar tags.

**Why is useful?** 
The primary e-commerce "objects" are [products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/products), [cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cart) and **[orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orders)**. So this old tag is really useful for search, indexing and filtering in this context.

**So for this particular case, it could be useful to create an [ecommerce-orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecommerce-orders) like** and make the necessary replacements.

Additionally, you can't remove all [orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orders) from all questions in StackOverFlow, just because you have post this question here, without looking to the context and asking top users of that tag before.

**To make things peaceful**, you could create some new replacement tags like in this particular case.

*I am concerned as I am the Top N°1 user for* [orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orders) *tag in StackOverFlow (but only in an e-commerce context).*

Comment: The issue isn't context. The issue is that people keep asking questions about how to take/make/process orders. The vast majority of questions you handle are perfectly valid questions about orders because they involve some form of coding. But take [this Magento question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45625400/magento-2-enter-custom-price-including-tax). It's not a coding question and should be closed as off-topic. There's several in there like that. [orders] is just too vague

Comment: @Machavity Ok sorry for this specific magento question (as I am only and exclusively skilled in WooCommerce taged questions). But in all the questions I answer with [tag:orders] the tag is really appropriated… I will create a specific e-commerce orders tag… In the meanwhile, please avoid to remove orders tag from WooCommerce questions, Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about burninating [order] or [orders]? If you're talking about [orders], [that was already declined](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338361/i-dont-accept-orders-from-you) :(

Comment: @pizzastaticvoidmain This is for [order], not [orders]