# I don't accept [orders] from you!

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

*The Phase #2 of the burnination process described  [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination), is completed and it has been decided that the tag should NOT be removed from the system.*

---

[orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orders) has 800+ questions and 4 followers.

The questions seem to be regarding various e-commerce packages such as [woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/woocommerce), [magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magento) and [bigcommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bigcommerce).

I think as long as the question is tagged with the software package it is using, [orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orders) is irrelevant.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324407/2675154

Comment: How, exactly, is a question proposing the burnination of [orders] a duplicate of a question proposing the burnination of [order]? I realize that it is only a one letter difference, but I don't see how it is a duplicate.

Comment: @TinyGiant from what I can see, honk was referring to the answer in that question that talks quite a bit about [orders]

Comment: @ChristopherPowell I was not addressing honk. Honk correctly stated that the referenced question is related. At the time that I left that comment, this question was [closed as a duplicate of that question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/338361/revisions). It has since been reopened. Some users must have fat-fingered that one.

Comment: It was not a fat finger. They are very closely related tags, and the discussion/actions should be consolidated in a single question. There are no arguments to be made for keeping [orders] but *not* keeping [order]. But you are free to disagree, @Tiny.

Comment: @cody [**DO NOT** try for a two-fer - one tag per discussion.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/288751) (emphasis original)

Comment: Related: [What tag(s) should be created for e-commerce/Magento/Amazon/etc. orders? and [orders] -> [ecommerce-orders]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367307/what-tags-should-be-created-for-e-commerce-magento-amazon-etc-orders-and-or)

Comment: There is at least actually **685 questions** tagged, **NOT 191**. As you are not really  involved in e-commerce answers, it's just easy to say *"Ok guys, look this tag is irrelevant"*… Sorry, but the tag **orders** is an **old tag** USEFUL and **RELEVANT** for **e-commerce** just like it is… This has been already discussed **multiple times before,** see my answer in [**this thread**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354967/3730754) for example and some others. So **NO BURNINATION**. There is many similar cases, where we could burninate a lot of existing tags. **Diversity make things rich**.

Comment: @Loic hey there. Indeed, no one can be an expert in all tags. By that logic however, any tag ever created should only be managed by their top users? That can't hold ground, there are guidelines, this needs more profound reasoning then "I'm the top user so don't burn this tag" present on all the threads you mention. What does it actually *bring*?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Sorry but I am not saying here that I am a top user… Just saying that orders tag is useful for e-commerce questions / answers. In e-commerce the primary "objects" are Products, Cart and **Orders**. So this old tag is useful for search, indexing and filtering in this context.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec This question was also created almost 2 years ago. The number of questions with the tag would have innevitably gone up.

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring: Q: +55/-3. A1 (Saying Yes): +5/-7.

Comment: **Moderator Note**: Please do not start removing the tag from questions until the community has decided whether to move forward with the burnination or not.

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring: Q: +76/-13 A1 (Saying Yes): +8/-16. A2 (Saying No): +13/-5. A3 (Saying yes): +5/-4. The community has voted in favor of not burninating the tag. If new evidence later warrants re-evaluation of this decision, a new proposal can be started.

Comment: @BhargavRao I'm confused - almost 6 times as many people voted "yes" on the question as voted "no." It seems like the community is, by and large, in *favor* of the burnination. (Although admittedly the answers are slightly more mixed).

Comment: @EJoshuaS, Don't take votes on the question to be "yes" or "no". There are other reasons to vote on the question, which include the fact that the topic is important and needs to be discussed. There are people who do vote because the pun was nice (before featuring), or even because it was featured. A lot of users also fall in the bracket between 15 and 125, who cannot downvote. (You can check [tag:chemistry] burn post, where the decision was to decline, and the score was at +68/-18). 10~12 downvotes during a burn is a very good signal to hold off (I usually check the answers while deciding too)

Comment: @EJoshuaS  See the process discussion here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination?noredirect=1&lq=1  TLDR, after being featured on the sidebar for increased visibility (its current state) the final call is made by moderators.

Comment: Also, as I stated, if new evidence later warrants re-evaluation of this decision, a new proposal can be started.

Comment: @BhargavRao Those are good points.

Answer (score 6):

Apart from what [Loic has already mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354967), [orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orders) has almost been exclusively used for orders related to e-commerce. Even when we check [mysql + orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orders+mysql), because [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) is the top related tag for [order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order), there are a handful of wrongly tagged one (like [database schema for recurring orders that change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086435/database-schema-for-recurring-orders-that-change) for example).

When we look at the related tags here, the top 8 of them are all related to e-commerce orders. Similarly, there are experts in that field who are the top users. All these individually point towards the good health of tag.

Finally, thanks to this highly specific role, most of the answers to the burnination questions are yes:

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

Yes, it does describe the contents of the question as related to e-commerce orders. And it is quite unambiguous, as it is being used for e-commerce related topics only.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Yes. Programming questions related to e-commerce orders and the related technologies are certainly on topic for Stack Overflow.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Yes, it does add meaningful information, as mentioned in Loic's answer.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

In the common context, orders does not just mean e-commerce orders in common context, it might be related to retail orders, court orders, or orderliness. (Note that I've not considered SQL order by clause, as I've not heard any one use orders while referring to that. I might be wrong here). However,  in the technical world, orders usually mean e-commerce orders, which it is being used for.

From all this, it is quite clear that the tag has a lot of value to remain. I think that the tag should not be burninated. I'm against renaming it to [e-commerce-orders], as usually we rename tags if it is ambiguous, whereas here, it is not.

Comment: You state that the answer to "Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?", is "No". But, that's one definition of ambiguous. In particular, it's a definition we use with tags. Tags should not take on different meanings based on context. However, in the next (last) paragraph you argue that the tag should not be renamed because it's unambiguous. Unambiguous is the opposite of not meaning the same in all common contexts. So, it appears what you're saying is in conflict with itself.

Comment: If the usage that's being chosen to be kept is encompassed by [e-commerce-orders] (which sounds like a good usage of the primarily intended concept), then the tag should be renamed as such, so that its use becomes unambiguous and people don't confuse it for other possible meanings of "orders". The resulting tag should be removed from all other uses, or they should be moved into their own tags.

Comment: @Makyen, slightly reworded the answer to fix the issues which you pointed out. Also, Shog9 mentions "Be aware though, this need only be a death sentence when one meaning is not far and away more common than all others - if a tag is used correctly most of the time, then just fix the instances where it isn't." for the last question. Here the tag is being used correctly most of the time, so renaming would not help much. (It will only cause confusion to those who are using it correctly). If it was being used wrongly in some 25% of the cases, then we should probably sit up and take notice.

Comment: "Programming questions related to e-commerce orders and the related technologies are certainly on topic for" - I don't really understand why this is special-casing orders, of all business concepts. I can understand security, APIs, databases, user interfaces and ecommerce itself all being technical topics around this area, but orders seems to be a bit like orderlines or deliveryaddresses: domain-relevant data models.

Comment: @RobertGrant, I'm not special casing order as such, but given that the question is about orders, I'm just mentioning about it. In fact, the 3 related tags of ecommerce apps, [tag:orders], [tag:product], [tag:cart] are all useful in distinguishing that a question is about orders, product, cart, and so on. It seems quite similar to datastructures, like [tag:list], [tag:dictionary], etc, which provide a suitable hint at what the question needs.

Answer (score 3):

I disagree with @BhargavRao's answer. I believe [orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orders) does meet the burnination criteria.

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

Not really. Most of the questions tagged with [orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orders) were asked before the current tag wiki/excerpt was made. It was and still is used for a huge variety of topics, and does not describe its contents well at all.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

It completely depends on how it is used.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Nope. I've seen questions about [woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/woocommerce), [e-commerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/e-commerce), [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), [export-to-csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/export-to-csv), etc. [orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orders) means something very different depending on the other tags it's used with.

Comment: Uh, for the last answer alone, [woocommerce] _is_ an [e-commerce] plugin for wordpress, written in [php]. The [export-to-csv] is used whenever the users want to export orders to CSV. I'm entirely not sure how you concluded that it means "something very different".

Comment: @BhargavRao I'm saying it means completely different things depending on the tags used with it.

Comment: That is wrong, I've checked most of them. Whenever it is tagged with [woocommerce], it is related to questions asking about orders using woocommerce. Similarly, for PHP, if you consider the questions that are not already tagged woocommerce, they are all related to Magento https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orders+php+-woocommerce. Again, Magento is an ecommerce platform written in PHP above Zend.

Comment: @BhargavRao exactly. It is used differently with woocommerce, php, and csv.

Comment: I'm not sure, why you're mentioning that it is being used differently. I've clearly informed you that whenever it is tagged with any of those, it is used for ecommerce orders only. Can you show me places where it is being used completely differently? (There certainly would be a couple of exceptions, which as Shog mentions, can just be retagged)

Comment: @BhargavRao it appears this one does: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53801028/shopify-api-get-order-via-tracking-number

Comment: and these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299996/shopware-rest-api-orders-list, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53375065/printing-11-what-i-view-in-prestashop

Comment: Again, [shopify] is an ecommerce platform, and the question is related to ecommerce orders. ("i want to get a shopify order via tracking_number."). So are [shopware] and [pretashop]. Think of this tag like [list], tagging it with [python] or [java] doesn't inherently change the meaning of the tag. Similarly, [orders] when tagged with different ecommerce tools, doesn't change the inherent meaning of the tag [orders].

Comment: Yes totally I agree with you: [Orders] tag does not meet the burnination criteria. This tag is very useful just like it's, for many reasons, when used in e-commerce context.

Answer (score -6):

Only useful as a meta-tag, which S.L. Barth tells me we don't want.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/woocommerce%20orders%20 has 76 questions
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magento%20orders?mode=all has 56 questions, and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bigcommerce%20orders?mode=all has 5 questions.

So **burninate**, but consider first creating woocommerce-orders, magento-orders, and bigcommerce-orders tags. (I don't know what the threshold is for tag creation.)

Comment: I'm pretty new at meta. What would make this better? Or is it just wrong (as, indeed, my other answer was)?

Comment: Hm, good question, actually... Meta can be pretty harsh. I wouldn't edit this answer, because an edit would bump the post and draw more attention to it. Better to let it slide into history. But to help you get started on Meta: a quick explanation why it is a meta-tag might have helped. I'm not sure that we need tags for "Woocommerce-orders", "Magento-orders" or "BigCommerce-orders". If you suggest disambiguation, make a case why the new tags would be needed.

Comment: That being said - welcome to Meta! You've had a harsh welcoming, but you're not alone in that. You may want to spend some time studying this site, and develop an intuition about what works here. I hope you'll become a valued contributor here.

Comment: @S.L.Barth, thanks for the kind words. I'd like to be a contributor, but breaking into SO is hard, because the easy stuff has been asked, and I'm not an expert in anything yet.