# Tag(s) for e-commerce/Magento/Amazon/etc. orders? and should [orders] -> [ecommerce-orders]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, tag-synonym-process, tag-disambiguation

There was [discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338361/i-dont-accept-orders-from-you) that the e-commerce related tag [orders] should be renamed [ecommerce-orders] since it is only used for e-commerce packages such as woocommerce, magento and bigcommerce.

Also, from [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324407/put-order-out-of-order/324444) there was consensus we need one or more tag(s) for e-commerce/Amazon/eBay orders.

- Can these all become [ecommerce-order]? or are some APIs so different, do we need separate:
- [order api: 60K results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=order+api+)
- [magento order: 6.1K results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=magento+order)
- [amazon order: 3.1K results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=amazon+order)
- [shopping cart order: 2.3K results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=shopping+cart+order)
- [ebay order: 400 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ebay+order)
- other tags: [magento2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magento2), [shopify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shopify), [woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/woocommerce), [wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress), [opencart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencart), [prestashop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prestashop), [nopcommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nopcommerce), [flipkart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flipkart)...

References:

Comment: I agree that the `order` tag (singular) is confusing and should be aliased, but `orders` tag (plural) is appropriated for e-commerce and should not need any changes… The tag ecommerce-orders is simply too long and not easy. For Woocommerce I could create specifically `wc-orders` or `wc-order`, but it seems that `orders` tag is appropriated for e-commerce only … see [this thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354967/3730754)

Comment: @LoicTheAztec: [orders] is way too close to [order] for confusion. Why not make [ecommerce-order] the main tag and alias to [orders]?

Comment: No I don't agree… `Orders` is just the right term appropriated for e-commerce context. I have already discussed that a lot of times before, and I keep my position. I am the top user of this tag in an e-commerce context. I always check and replace `order` by `orders` tag in all `woocommerce` tagged questions...

Comment: @LoicTheAztec: I already knew you're the top user of [orders] in e-commerce context, I read the previous discussion I cited. But you really think [order] and [orders] are not too close for confusion? What does everyone else here suggest?

Comment: In my area of action which is specifically Woocommerce tagged questions, I take time to explain, to edit questions, to change tags if needed… Now confusion is everywhere and all the time for anything… So you can act yourself for that community everyday, helping in your action area as you can.