# End of the summer [sales]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

There are only 148 questions tagged with the [sales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sales) tag right now, but it's a mess of a tag, and it seems like a very meta tag.  It has no tag wiki or information.  Only one of the top 20 answerers has answered more than one question in the tag (and they've answered 2); only two of the top 20 askers has asked more than one question (but they've asked 2).  There have been only 4 new questions in the last 30 days.

There are questions about sales calculations, sales information, sale confirmations, sales metrics... you name it.  It also draws in a small amount of off-topic posts because... sales.

It looks like almost all of those questions could exist without the [sales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sales) tag, and the ones that can't... well, bye?

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring: Q: +163/-3.  No answers.

Comment: **Moderator Notes** 1. Please do not start burninating the tag until we reach a decision 2. The comments on this post have been cleaned to facilitate discussion about the burnination of this tag. Feel free to hold off on the puns and other tag burnination suggestions until the end of the burnination process.

Comment: Would that be a fire sale?

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring: Q: +208/-5. A1 (saying yes): +41/-1. The community has voted in favor of burnination.

Comment: @pjmorse: Yeah, so many missed opportunities with the title. But it is a hard sell.

Comment: [status-burninated]!

Answer (score 44):

I am for burnination of the original [sales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sales) tag as it seems to be being misused a lot (after checking the deleted questions). Even though the primary purpose of the tag seems to be for e-commerce, it is not being used properly, unlike the [orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orders) tag, where it was mainly being used for e-commerce questions specifically.

There are questions with the tag, where, the poster has a table called "sales" in their database, needs help with getting the SEO fixed to increase their sales, and of course the occasional [sales advice related questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7GXA.png).

That said, a significant majority of questions seems to be about e-commerce sales, including the [Magento Sales library](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/sales/sales.html), [Net suite sales orders](https://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2017_1/schema/record/salesorder.html?mode=package), and so on. These questions need a generic tag created in order to classify them in the bucket of "E-Commerce Sales". I would just go for a [ecommerce-sales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecommerce-sales) for now, and then rename the tag later, if required.

Comment: Do we need a generic ecommerce-sales tag? Why not just require the specific application/platform tag? There's already a [tag:transactions] tag for the generic concept of a sale transaction being performed, if someone has a question about sales transactions that's somehow related to programming.

Comment: @TylerH [Transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/transactions/info) is a programming concept. No relation to exchange of goods and services.

Comment: @TylerH, If you were to take on that direction, I'd rather say that [tag:orders] would be apt as compared to [tag:transactions], as in the world of e-commerce, "sales transactions" are called "sales orders". That said, there are a lot of programming questions about the sales shipments, sales bills, and so on, which do not relate to sale transactions/orders. "Sales" can possibly be mentioned as a combination of "orders" and "accounts". I am no expert in this field, so do take my argument with a pinch of salt.

Comment: @jpaugh Transactions in programming are so named because of the broader definition, which definitely applies to an atomic exchange of a good or service. A transaction is what you call a change of state in a collection, be that collection a database or some other entity. Typically (though not always), it's an exchange of one thing for another. However, I'm certainly open to better tag options, if they exist (as Bhargav has suggested, for example).

Comment: @BhargavRao Hasn't the [tag:orders] tag been burninated like twice already (or attempted)?

Comment: @TylerH We burned the [order](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324407/youre-out-of-order-youre-out-of-order-the-whole-site-is-out-of-order) tag, orders was declined for [burn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338361/i-dont-accept-orders-from-you) or [merge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367307/tags-for-e-commerce-magento-amazon-etc-orders-and-should-orders-ecomme).  You can use [Rodgort](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/requests) to search for burn requests

Comment: @TylerH, as Dan mentioned, we burned the [order] tag. [orders] has been relatively cleaner and specific to e-commerce questions. The users of the tag have curated the content there.

Answer (score 8):

[sales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sales) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- Questions related to e-commerce sales should be tagged with [ecommerce-sales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecommerce-sales) instead.

## Progress:

The [sales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sales) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions (to improve the question *and* remove the tag),
- **flagging/closing** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based,
- filtering on this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=sales),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsales%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsales%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsales%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsales%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## [Track progress of the burnination!](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197642)

[Dashboard for progress](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=385971)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [sales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sales) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance".

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [sales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sales) tag — just flag/vote to close the question.

#### Do not downvote questions in order to trigger roomba

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [sales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sales) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.