# We will gladly take your [money]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, synonym-request

[money](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/money)

It's a thing. While we write programs to take it, move it around, [lose it](https://dougseven.com/2014/04/17/knightmare-a-devops-cautionary-tale/), etc, it's not really a good tag. A better tag is [currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/currency), which takes into account an actual usage. Here's the excerpts

[money] (470 questions)

> This tag is for general money related issues, such as representation, format, processing, internationalization and localization.

[currency] (1700+ questions)

> Currency is a medium of exchange of value, usually referring to government issued denominations.

So there's a couple of ways to play this

1. Burninate [money] - Retag (probably to [currency]), close and delete. You know the drill
   [image]
2. Make [money] a synonym of [currency]. Not as sexy

Either way, this tag has to go

[image]

Comment: I would argue that there are experts at money and currency, but then I remember that this is not an economist site but a programmers'.

Comment: @ChristianDean Money money money, must be fun-ny ...

Comment: 'money' in general could potentially include cryptocurrency, but is [tag:currency] supposed to include [tag:cryptocurrency]? (I don't want to see a tag [tag:fiat-currency]. So maybe you need a note in the tag definition of currency)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Merging with [currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/currency) seems like the best choice here: majority of questions appear to be about representing currency in whatever system, with a smattering concerning some Ruby gem and the remaining few hopelessly off-topic.

July 3rd: I went ahead and merged these, leaving a synonym for [money](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/money).

Comment: That would work. I wasn't sure if we needed to burninate first

Comment: So, cleanup first?

Comment: Yeah, I did a quick pass @Braiam.

Answer (score -11):

I dunno, I think questions about [the SQL Server datatype `money`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/money-and-smallmoney-transact-sql) should reasonably be able to be tagged [money](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/money)...

Comment: Probably should use a specialized tag like [sql-money] or [sql-server-money] for that. We have a [similar problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324407/put-order-out-of-order) with [order] and [sql-order-by]. Keeps it inline with tags like [mysql-json]

Comment: I'd agree if more than a tiny fraction of questions used it for that purpose. In practice, more folks appear to use it for [tag:ruby]'s money library, and even *those* are probably no more than a 10th of all questions in the tag. By far the common case appears to be... Folks talking about working with money in code, which is the same meaning as [tag:currency]