# Merge tags [order-of-operations], [order-of-evaluation], and [operator-precedence]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The [order] tag is in the process of being [burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324407/712765). As part of that cleanup, I suggest merging the [order-of-operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order-of-operations), [order-of-evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order-of-evaluation), and [operator-precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/operator-precedence) tags.

We have 92 questions tagged [order-of-operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order-of-operations), 315 tagged [order-of-evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order-of-evaluation), and 748 tagged [operator-precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/operator-precedence), with of course some questions having more than one of these tags. I can see no evidence that anyone thinks these tags are about different things. They all concern the rules of a programming language (or math in general, which is off topic for SO) for the order in which operators are applied (a.k.a. sub-expressions evaluated) when there are multiple operators in a single expression or language statement.

Since [operator-precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/operator-precedence) has the most questions, I suggest we keep it and make the other two synonyms. This would also mean merging/moving [evaluation-order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/evaluation-order) which is currently a synonym for [order-of-evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order-of-evaluation).

Although I favor keeping [operator-precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/operator-precedence) both because it has the most questions and because it is the standard term used in the computer science literature, it seems somewhat obvious to me that [order-of-operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order-of-operations) has the best tag wiki description, so I recommend transferring that to whichever tag we decide should become the master tag.

Side note: I believe [order-of-execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order-of-execution) should remain distinct and be used to refer to the order in which higher level actions are taken, such as the order in which JavaScript executes event handlers or databases fire triggers relative to evaluating constraints.

Answer (score 5):

[order-of-evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order-of-evaluation) has a tag wiki that states that it is about "well-defined rules stating the order in which expressions are evaluated", which is very similar to that of [order-of-operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order-of-operations), which is "The set of rules within a programming language that determine the order in which operators are applied when evaluating an expression or statement containing multiple operators". When I checked the questions, in almost all of the cases, they both have been used to convey the same meaning.

However, there is one other point. The tag wiki of [order-of-operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order-of-operations) seems to be very well written. Therefore, if we were to synonymize [order-of-operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order-of-operations) to [order-of-evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order-of-evaluation), we probably should be carrying over the tag wiki to the other one.

Given that there are more questions in [order-of-evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order-of-evaluation), it does seem the best to use that as the master. Also, [order-of-evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order-of-evaluation) already has a [evaluation-order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/evaluation-order), which would have to be removed, in case we decide that [order-of-operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order-of-operations) should be the master.

That said, there is another [operator-precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/operator-precedence), which is also about order of evaluation of expressions, and the tag wiki mentions "In mathematics and computer programming, the order of operations (sometimes called operator precedence) is a rule used to clarify unambiguously which procedures should be performed first in a given mathematical expression.". If we were to include this tag, then [operator-precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/operator-precedence) would be the master and the others (3 in total) would be its synonyms.

Comment: I didn't notice the [tag:operator-precedence] tag and I totally agree it should be the new master tag. I have updated my post accordingly.

Comment: Cool, I'll leave it for a couple of days to see if anyone has any opposing views, before acting on this.

Comment: Looks like we missed one: [tag:precedence]. Can you point that to [tag:operator-precedence] too, or do I need to open a new request?

Comment: Done. Checked the first page, and all 50 were related to operator precedence.