# Merge [execution-order] and [order-of-execution]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

In [order-of-execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order-of-execution) there's a wiki

> Questions about the order in which various events occur in a software system. For example, the order in which queued asynchronous tasks are executed in JavaScript or the order in which triggers are called and constraints are checked in SQL. Distinct from [operator-precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/operator-precedence), which covers the order in which operators are applied when evaluating an expression in a programming language.

The [execution-order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/execution-order) has no wiki and only (currently) 39 questions compared to 59 in the other tag

I think both should be merged

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, this makes sense. We already merged [order-of-evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order-of-evaluation), and [evaluation-order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/evaluation-order) in another similar request [Merge tags [order-of-operations], [order-of-evaluation], and [operator-precedence]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/379343/4099593).

I went through the list of questions and it seems like the tags are being used for the same thing. I merged the tags in this order: [order-of-execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order-of-execution) ← [execution-order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/execution-order), as it had more questions and a better wiki.