# Move [order-of-evaluation], [order-of-operations], and [evaluation-order] synonyms to [order-of-execution]

Tags: feature-request, retag-request

The [order-of-evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order-of-evaluation), [order-of-operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order-of-operations), and [evaluation-order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/evaluation-order) synonyms are falsely linking to [operator-precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/operator-precedence). They should instead be synonyms for [order-of-execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order-of-execution).

I believe the status quo started with this request: [Merge tags [order-of-operations], [order-of-evaluation], and [operator-precedence]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/379343/5740428)

#### Technical explanation: distinction between operator precedence and order of execution

It may not be entirely obvious, so let me elaborate on the terminology.

In an expression such as `a() + b() + c()`:

- **Operator precedence** tells us that this is grouped as `(a() + b()) + c()`. However, the precedence in itself does not specify whether `a()`, `b()`, or `c()` are executed first. In some languages, there is a left-to-right evaluation guarantee. However, in C and C++, this is not the case, and `a()`, `b()`, and `c()` can be invoked in an arbitrary order by the compiler.
- **Order of execution** is the overarching concept, although it does not dictate *which* operations are executed in the first place. It not only includes the fact that the addition of `a()` and `b()` has to happen prior to the addition with `c()`, but also includes in what order the functions are invoked.

As a rule of thumb:

> **Operator precedence** states *which* operations take place, and **order of execution** states in what order all the operations occur. These two concepts somewhat intersect though.

Therefore, the [order-of-evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order-of-evaluation) and [evaluation-order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/evaluation-order) are falsely equated with "operator precedence" through the current synonym.

#### Intuitive linguistic explanation

Even ignoring all the technical aspects, it makes very little sense why [order-of-evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order-of-evaluation) is not a synonym for [order-of-execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order-of-execution), since "evaluation" and "execution" are basically the same thing.

#### Practical Issues

An unsuspecting user may be asking a C++ question such as this:

> #### Is the order of initialization guaranteed for globals?
>
> Is the order in which global variable initializers are evaluated guaranteed?
>
> ```cpp
> int x = 1; // global variable
> int y = x + 1; // is this guaranteed to be 2?
> ```
>
> [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer), [order-of-evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order-of-evaluation)

The poor fool would have inadvertently tagged their question as [operator-precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/operator-precedence) despite not asking about operator precedence at all.

In practice, it looks like virtually all uses of [operator-precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/operator-precedence) use this tag, and not one of its synonyms. If there is a way to get specific numbers for how many questions would be affected, I would appreciate some advice.

#### Conclusion

It would be more appropriate to turn the tags in question into a synonym for [order-of-execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order-of-execution).