# Which tag should be used if there is a question about the Angular directive NgIf?

Tags: discussion, tags

Which tag should be used if there is a question about the [Angular directive NgIf](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html)?

**Available tags**

In order to find the correct tag, `ngif` was queried in the tags section. The three most relevant results are as follows:

- [ngif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ngif):

> NGif is an open-source tool that creates the ability for .Net to
>   make/read Animated Gifs

- [angularjs-ng-if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-if):

> The ngIf directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree
>   based on an {expression}. If the expression assigned to ngIf evaluates
>   to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a
>   clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM.

- [angular-ng-if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ng-if):

> an angular js core directive that toggles the presence of the targeted
>   element in the dom

**Discussion**

- It looks like the [ngif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ngif) tag is misused several times as it is
  assigned to Angular related questions while the tag is about .Net.
- Should [angularjs-ng-if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-if) or [angular-ng-if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ng-if) be used? Another Angular directive, e.g. [NgFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ngfor) does not have a `angular-ng` prefix. The naming convention looks inconsistent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should angularjs-ng-if or angular-ng-if be used?

The two tags mean *exactly the same*, so they should be [synonymized](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms). On the other hand, **do we really need those tags?** They seem rather specialized to me, but I'm not a domain expert here.

> It looks like the ngif tag is misused several times as it is assigned to Angular related questions while the tag is about .Net.

Tags should be *unambiguous*, so the correct action is here to remove that tag on those questions (or replace it with one of the angular- ones). Be sure to improve other issues with the post (grammar etc.) as well, otherwise your suggested edits might get rejected.

Comment: [Burninate 73 AngularJS directive tags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296857/burninate-73-angularjs-directive-tags)

Comment: `angularjs` is way enough. It's pretty basic stuff. There is a high chance that the question would just be about something that didn't refresh because he didn't use dot notation or a typo.