# Could someone rename ngif to .net-ngif?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

The [ngif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ngif) tag is about a .net tool, but in the majority of the cases it is seen by the users as a tag that is about the [ngif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ngif) directive of angular2. Could someone rename this tag to [.net-ngif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-ngif) or [n-gif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/n-gif) to prevent further misuse?

Comment: [Very related](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339230/which-tag-should-be-used-if-there-is-a-question-about-the-angular-directive-ngif).

Answer (score 1):

There are totally 213 questions that have been tagged with [ngif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ngif), out of which:

- [182 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bngif%5D%20%5Bangular%5D%20is%3Aq&mixed=0) are also tagged with [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular)
- [13 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bngif%5D+-%5Bangular%5D+%22angular%22+is%3Aq&mixed=0) have the word "Angular" but are not tagged [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular)
- [7 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bngif%5D%20-%5Bangular%5D%20-%22angular%22%20%5Bangularjs%5D%20is%3Aq&mixed=0) that are not about Angular, have the tag [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs)
- [3 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bngif%5D%20-%5Bangular%5D%20-%22angular%22%20-%5Bangularjs%5D%20is%3Aq%20%5Bionic3%5D&mixed=0) are about Ionic3
- [2 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bngif%5D%20-%5Bangular%5D%20-%22angular%22%20-%5Bangularjs%5D%20is%3Aq%20%5Bionic-framework%5D&mixed=0) are about Ionic Framework
- [1 question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bngif%5D%20-%5Bangular%5D%20-%22angular%22%20-%5Bangularjs%5D%20is%3Aq%20%5Bangular6%5D&mixed=0) is about Angular 6
- [1 question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bngif%5D%20-%5Bangular%5D%20-%22angular%22%20-%5Bangularjs%5D%20is%3Aq%20%5Bangular5%5D&mixed=0) is about Angular 5
- [1 question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bngif%5D%20-%5Bangular%5D%20-%22angular%22%20-%5Bangularjs%5D%20is%3Aq%20%5Bprimeng%5D&mixed=0) is about PrimeNG

If we remove [all of these questions, we are left with 4 posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bngif%5D+-%5Bangular%5D+-%22angular%22+-%5Bangularjs%5D+is%3Aq+-%5Bionic3%5D+-%5Bionic-framework%5D+-%5Bangular6%5D+-%5Bangular5%5D+-%5Bprimeng%5D&mixed=0), that are actually about the .net-ngif, and therefore it doesn't make much sense to rename it now. My proposal is to instead:

- Retag the 4 questions about the .NET ngif to [.net-ngif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-ngif), using the previous tag wiki

  > Use this tag for questions about NGif, the .NET library for making and reading animated GIFs. Do NOT use this tag for questions about the NgIf directive in Angular or AngularJS: AngularJS (version 1.x) questions should be tagged [angularjs] and [angularjs-ng-if]; questions concerning Angular (version 2 and higher) should be tagged [angular] and [angular-ng-if].
- Retag the 7 questions about AngularJS ngif to [angularjs-ng-if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-if)
- Merge the [ngif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ngif) tag with [angular-ng-if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ng-if).

This is trivial to accomplish and should take a maximum of 3 minutes.