# We should get rid of synonyms for some of the AngularJS ngmodel tags

Tags: discussion, retag-request, synonym-request

While editing a low profile question on AngularJS `ng-model`s, I've came across three tags that (seem to) describe the same component in AngularJS.

[ngmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ngmodel) (12 questions tagged, this one doesn't even have a usage guidance)

[angular-ngmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ngmodel) (1,006 questions tagged)

[angularjs-ng-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-model) (351 questions tagged)

All three tags show a question relevant to both AngularJS (the 1.x versions) and AngularJS 2 (the 2.x versions).

We already have [angular2-ngmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-ngmodel) (no usage guidance) points to the appropriate version.

I think the questions in [ngmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ngmodel) and [angularjs-ng-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-model) tags should be merged with [angular-ngmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ngmodel), except the Angular2 questions that should be merged with [angular2-ngmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-ngmodel).

Comment: "Burnination" is not a synonym of "merged".

Comment: i meant to burn the tags, after migrating the questions to different tags

Comment: If there are no questions with a tag, the tag doesn't need to be burned. It just disappears automatically. And since what we're doing here is merging and/or synonymizing the tags, there is no need for burnination. (I know, everyone uses this term, and it sounds cool, but it's often not really what you want to do.)

Comment: Can you suggest why we need any of these tags in the first place?

Comment: we don't need any more synonym tags, we should nullify them

Comment: I already added a link to a related / duplicate request [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296857/burninate-73-angularjs-directive-tags), but apparently it was auto-deleted by closing and reopening.